# Google maps: render map based on street address

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I thought would be rather simple, guess not. I have user profiles on my site, each profile have a street address (format: 1234 Some Street, City, State, Zip).

I want to add map a small map on the page based on that information (not longitude and latitude...).

**Is there a plugin that can do this simple task?** Reading through google docs are a headache and seems to making this simple task much harder than it needed to be.

**EDIT: I want that javascript map, not static**

Answer (score 0):

The [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) might be what you're looking for.

> Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use to place markers or position the map.
>
> ...
>
> The Google Maps API provides a geocoder class for geocoding and reverse geocoding dynamically from user input.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah just use something like:

```
<img align='top' border="1" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=An        
reagan, Drummond Rd, Evanton, Dingwall, Ross-Shire IV16 9UT    
&maptype=roadmap&zoom=14&size=500x350&sensor=false&maptype=HYBRID&markers=color:blue|label:An Creagan, Drummond Rd, 
Evanton, Dingwall, Ross-Shire IV16 9UT|An Creagan, Drummond Rd, Evanton, Dingwall, Ross-Shire IV16 9UT" alt="A & A Cleaning Service">
```

Comment: is it possible to use the dynamic maps opposed to static this way?

Comment: yes, in PHP I did it as follows (click on link to see what): <img align='top' border="1" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=<?=$address?>&maptype=roadmap&zoom=14&size=500x350&sensor=false&maptype=HYBRID&markers=color:blue|label:<?=$address?>|<?=$address?>" alt="<?=$company?>">

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

> http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/

It comes with intuitive examples on how get started quickly using the Google Maps API.

One example: Street view

> http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/examples/streetview.html

Comment: Saying "it doesn't work" doesn't help me help you. Be more descriptive.